STM32 ADC doesn't work when connected to circuit
When I connect my STM32L432kc ADC to the circuit, it stops working. Without connection it acts perfectly (fig. 2), but when I connect it gives (fig. 3). I thought the buffer would help, but it didn't. How to solve this problem?




When connecting the gnd of the stm to the overall gnd, it works, but the modulation stops working.

The problem was indeed that the stm had to be connected to the gnd of the board. The modulation did not stop working, but was clipped by my other circuit due to the difference of the gnd.

The problem was indeed that the stm had to be connected to the gnd of the board. The modulation did not stop working, but was clipped by my other circuit due to the difference of the gnd.
